# How to addUser to a Tenant in Stratos?

Tags: wso2, wso2-stratos

I am trying to figure out how to adduser to a tenant in Stratos 1.5.1

I have success in adding a user to just the Users in ldap.

I have been using

```
org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.api.WSUserStoreManager
```

and then I use the method addUser

But, I am unable to figure out how to add user to the domain or tenant specific ldap entry.

```
Does anybody have  a proper example to do this?
```

Should I  be using this web service ?

```
org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.api.WSRealmTenantManager
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create (or register) a tenant with domain foo.com,you have to login as admin@foo.com to add user to user store of that tenant.You said you have been success in adding  user to super tenant, in that case you should log in using admin credentials (default admin,admin).  Now use username with tenant domain (admin@foo.com).